# Django URL wildcard with reverse?

Tags: django, django-urls

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#example), it say that URL's are tested from top to bottom:

> /articles/2003/ would match the first pattern in the list, not the second one, because the patterns are tested in order, and the first one is the first test to pass. Feel free to exploit the ordering to insert special cases like this. Here, Django would call the function views.special_case_2003(request)

But this is not happening in my experience - I want the last URL to be a wildcard to match whatever is not caught by any of the other rules, but this rule ends up catching everything. I have tried putting it at the top, and at the bottom.

Here are the requirements:
 - Anything not caught by other rules should match `home`.
 - Reverse for `home` should match the shortest accepted URL, in this case it would be blank.

How can this be accomplished?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('project.api')),
    url(r'^', include('places.urls')),
]
```

`places.urls`:

```
app_name = 'places'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=app_name + '/detail.html'), name='detail'),
    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=app_name + '/home.html'), name='home'), # Single page app
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to catch all other urls and redirect to the url for home, which will keep a consistent urlconf for home. Code shown below, but if you'd prefer that any other urls go straight to home without a redirect, just change the view referenced by the final `url` in `urlpatterns` below.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('project.api')),
    url(r'^', include('places.urls')),
    # catch all other urls
    url(r'^.*/$', views.redirect_to_home,name='redirect-to-home'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

def redirect_to_home(request):
    # assuming home has an urlconf name of 'home'
    return redirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
```

Comment: Would this redirect change the URL in the browser?

Comment: Yes; if you'd rather not do that you can instead just route to the view for home (and the url will stay the same while returning home for any wildcard url) - `url(r'^.*/$', views.home,name='home'),` (route to the view for `home` for the second arg)